# How to use multiple private keys in one inventory of Ansible

Tags: ssh, key, ansible

I have an ansible inventory which looks like:

```
# Create an OSEv3 group that contains the masters and nodes groups
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=centos

# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_sudo must be set to true
ansible_sudo=true

product_type=openshift
deployment_type=enterprise

# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to DenyAllPasswordIdentityProvider
#openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/openshift/openshift-passwd'}]

# host group for masters
[masters]
master.example.com

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
master.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}"
node1.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"
node2.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
```

Now I need keys to make the host accessible for ansible.
I have 2 keys. One for my master and one for my nodes. How can I change this script to tell ansible about which key it must use?

The script will be executed on my master. My master contains the 2 keys in `/root/.ssh/`

At the moment I only now `private_key_file` in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` but that can only configured with one standard key for Ansible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define [behavioral parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) in your inventory. Either behind each host or in a separate `group:vars` section. Since you have multiple nodes which share the same key the latter makes more sense:

```
[masters:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=1.pem

[nodes:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=2.pem
```

Comment: I get: ERROR: /etc/ansible/hosts:30: variables assigned to group must be in key=value form

Comment: Aaand you have them in `key=value` format? Can you add your update to your question above?

Comment: nvm it works now: I had to define: ansible_ssh_private_key_file=....pem (you may edit it in your answer)

Comment: I can't follow you. I have the key=value notation in my answer.

Comment: Ow damn yes. I was wrong sorry. Thought it was a long name of your .pem. I was too quick, sorry and thanks for the right answer.